# Are there any problems handling a POST request as a GET request on the server

Tags: perl, cgi, http-headers

In an attempt to resolve the issue I posted in this question:

[Is it possible to send POST parameters to a CGI script using a system() call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853421/is-it-possible-to-send-post-parameters-to-a-cgi-script-using-a-system-call)

So far the only successful resolution to the problem is to trick the environment to think the request was a GET.  I do this by converting the POST parameters to a query string, saving that string in the default environment variable, then changing the environment variable that tells the server what method this request is using to GET.

```
$ENV{'QUERY_STRING'} = $long_parameter_string . '&' . $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} = 'GET';

system {$perl_exec} $cgi_script;
```

I'm essentially tricking the CGI module to read from the QUERY_STRING environment variable instead of from STDIN, which it would attempt to read POST requests from.

This method seems to work so far, but I'm worried about unintended repercussions.

My question is, do you see any potential problems with this?

Comment: To be clear, I'm not attempting to start a philosophical argument on whether this is the "right" thing to do.  I would like to know of potential problems that might arise and need to be tested for.  This is simply a pragmatic solution to an odd real-world problem I'm running into.

Comment: I changed this to a community wiki as I don't think that there's necessarily a correct answer.

Comment: You seem to have ignored the suggestion to open a pipe to the process and write to it. If you want to test a POST, stop trying to force system() into it. There are many other tools in the Perl toolbox.

Comment: I didn't ignore it, it's actually in the example code of my original problem and I left comments regarding this for the two people who answered.  Piping passes the parameters, but still truncates them.  Also, as this issue relates to my original problem, it may be better addressed in the thread for that problem.

Comment: Set the environment, open a pipe, and write to it. Don't put your data on the command line. Check out the CGI protocol to see what you need to do.

Comment: Even though I've found out what the issue is with my original question and no longer need to use this method, I never found a serious issue with doing this, if needed.  Other than perhaps a moral one, as people seem to taken great offense to even the idea of this.  Please continue to post potential problems related to this question (hint: they have nothing to do with pipes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll hit problems with larger submissions and file-uploads as the size limit for a GET is much smaller than a POST. If you're talking about predictably small amounts of data, you should be alright.

Comment: Well, the original problem centers around fairly large requests.  However, I assumed that the limitations to the size of GET were mostly a product of the limit of a URL in most browsers.  I don't figure Perl's CGI module nor the Linux environment variable offers any serious size limitations seeing it's running on a 64-bit machine.

As far as file uploads go, the CGI module has already had a chance to handle the file and the temporary location should be all that left in the parameters.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.  I'm in the process of testing this now.

Comment: Chosen for best answer so far since it's the only one that defines a possible problem, which was the point of the question.

Answer (score 2):

POST and GET **mean** entirely different things, and you shouldn't be "testing" anything that way.

Instead, you should do a real POST to the intended URL by using Perl's [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-5.834/lwpcook.pod#POST).

```
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
use LWP::UserAgent;
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $req = POST 'http://www.perl.com/cgi-bin/BugGlimpse',
              [ param1 => 'arbitrarily long blob', param2 => 'whatever' ];

print $ua->request($req)->as_string;
```

Comment: Please see my original problem there's a link for above.  

There are two reasons I'm not doing this, though.  One, I'm using mod_rewrite to redirect all requests to the file that ultimately executes the intended CGI script.  Two, I could put a special parameter or something in the request you suggested to make sure mod_rewrite is bypassed, but that would ultimately lead to more request time than I'm comfortable with.

Comment: Your comment is a non sequitur. mod_rewrite has nothing to do with anything that pertains to HTTP method.

Comment: No, but it pertains to my original problem and the reason I'm handling the request this way in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the input Jonathan.  This is probably the correct way of handling this situation for most people.